# Adjusting pulse amplitude against fixed noise variance to achieve a given Eb/No

Tags: noise, amplitude, simulink, pulse

Given a short duration pulse of $n$ samples out of a frame of $L$ samples, and amplitude of each of these samples being $A$, and an AWGN channel with variance $\sigma ^{2} = 1$, how can I derive $A$ such that the resulting $E_{b}/N_{0}$ (dB) value is equal to a specified value?

In case it is relevant, this would be implemented in a frame based Simulink model.

Comment: "pulse" is a bit of an ambiguous term. I *think* you mean "I transmit zeros for the whole frame of length $L$, except for a duration of $n$ samples, where I transmit samples with $|\text{sample}| = A$." Is that understanding correct?

Comment: That is correct, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The energy of noise in your $L$-length frame is simply $L\cdot \sigma^2$.

The energy of your pulse is $n\cdot \lvert A\rvert^2$.

The SNR over the whole frame hence is $\frac nL \frac{\lvert A\rvert^2}{\sigma^2}$.

The SNR, **only** looking during the pulse itself, is $\frac nn \frac {\lvert A\rvert^2}{\sigma^2}=\frac {\lvert A\rvert^2}{\sigma^2}$.

Since these are *power*/*energy* values, the usual decibel definition $x_{[\text{dB}]}=10\log_{10}(x_{\text{lin.}})$ applies.

To go from SNR to $E_b/N_0$, you'd need to define how many **bits of information** your pulse carries! But then, it's really just dividing the energy you transmit by the number of bits to get $E_b$, and $N_0$ is really just the noise energy per sample (here).

Comment: So in the scenario that it is a single bit per pulse, it is possible to equate $E_{b}/N_{0}$ to the SNR?

Comment: The single bit "owns" all the energy in the pulse. So $E_b$ is indeed $n\cdot |A|^2$. However, your $N_0$ is the per-sample noise energy, not the integral.

Comment: To bring this back full circle: let us assume an arbitrary $E_{b}/N_{0} = 13$ dB, where I wish to derive $A$. Is it as simple as $A = \sqrt{ \sigma^{2} \cdot E_{b}/N_{0} } = \sqrt{13_{dB}} $ (where the dB value is converted to linear)?

Comment: Quickly chiming back in to check if this is appropriate?